# openSUSE Linux: No Provider for libglib-dev libgcrypt-dev found

Tags: linux, package, opensuse, suse, libgcrypt

i try to install the packages libglib-dev libgcrypt-dev via `sudo apt-get install ...` on openSUSE Leap 42.2.

The trouble is it claims, that there is *"No provider of 'libglib2.0-devel' found."* (same for libgcrypt-dev) Is it possible, that the packages just aren't available for openSUSE or there are similar ones but with different names?

During the process of searching a solution, i messed with the repositories but was able to reset them to the original ones. I was able to install libglib-2_0-0 manually from https://software.opensuse.org/package/libglib-2_0-0 but it didn't seem to solve the problem.

Do you have a solution?

Comment: the wanted packages are part of this command: sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev libgcrypt20-dev autoconf automake libtool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install` on openSUSE ? this is Debian package management .. openSUSE is rpm based distribution with **`zypper`** package management tool.

And package names you trying install are for debian/ubuntu system and don't exist under this names in openSUSE

Correct devel packages on openSUSE are : 
**libgcrypt-devel** and **glib2-devel**

Please don't blindly copy install instructions from web intended for different distribution

so -> `sudo zypper in libgcrypt-devel glib2-devel autoconf automake libtool`

Comment: thank you! it really was the the different names. in general how can i find out what the referring name of the package in openSUSE is? and anouther question: what what means the extension "-dev" behind a packagename?

Comment: _-dev_ in **debian** and _-devel_ in **rpm based distros** means files for development -> needed for compilation / building packages from source code whit dependency on this package. This packages also pulls all needed lib / tools etc packages.

Comment: For searching packages you can use `zypper se` command and useful is also `zypper info` in openSUSE